# Amazon s3 - ruby. Get the URL of the resource that was just uploaded

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have the following code that is used to upload a local file to Amazon S3 Bucket:

```
require 'aws/s3'
module AmazonS3

  def self.upload_file(local_file)
    bucket_name = "bucketfortest"

      s3 = AWS::S3.new(
        :access_key_id     => ENV["AMAZON_ACCESS_KEY"], 
        :secret_access_key => ENV["AMAZON_SECRET_KEY"] 
      )


    key = File.basename(local_file)

    amazon_object = s3.buckets[bucket_name].objects[key].write(:file => local_file)
    return amazon_object #How can I get the URL of the object here?

  end
end
```

I based this code on: [Upoad file S3](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UploadObjSingleOpRuby.html)
I am trying to find out a way to get the URL of the object that was just uploaded, but I fail to find what is it. I tried `.url` , but that gives me an Undefined Method. I fail to see anything in the docs either.

Comment: Don't S3 urls simply follow a fixed layout? Something like <region>.amazonaws.com/<your_bucket>/<your_file>, or <your_bucket>.s3.amazonaws.com/<your_file>. You could take a look at how `fog` constructs URLs for clues (actually, use fog--it's pretty nice to use.)

Comment: What about `.public_url` ?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I haven't used the Ruby AWS SDK at all but it looks like you could do this:

Get the [public URL](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSRubySDK/latest/AWS/S3/S3Object.html#public_url-instance_method):

```
return amazon_object.public_url
```

Or a [signed URL for a private object](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSRubySDK/latest/AWS/S3/S3Object.html#url_for-instance_method):

```
return amazon_object.url_for(:read, :expires => 10*60)
```

Answer (score 2):

You know the url because it's the same url as the local file's filename. So you can compose the url from the filename and the bucket name, without getting any info from S3 other than success.